# UIViewAnimationTransitionCurlUp from right to left in landscape (both left and right) orientation

Tags: iphone, animation, uiview, orientation, landscape

I'm trying to make a transition between two views with UIViewAnimationTransitionCurlUp.
My application works in landscape (left and right) and I need transition from right to left.
UIViewAnimationTransitionCurlUp works from down to up (and not from right to left as I want).
My first version was:

```
self.oneView = [[[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:frame] autorelease];
self.twoView = [[[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:frame] autorelease];
[self.view addSubview:self.oneView];

[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:1];
[UIView setAnimationTransition:UIViewAnimationTransitionCurlUp forView:self.view cache:YES];
[self.oneView removeFromSuperview];
[self.view addSubview:twoView];
[UIView commitAnimations];
```

It worked in landscape with home button on the right (transition was from right to left started with right-upper corner as desired).
But when device was rotated to home button on the left, curl affect was upside down: from left to right started with left-buttom corner).
It seemed that animation wasn't aware of device orientation.
I changed a code in order to use intermediate container view (between self.view and

```
self.oneView/twoView):
self.containerView = [[[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:frame] autorelease];
self.oneView = [[[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:frame] autorelease];

self.twoView = [[[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:frame] autorelease];
[self.view addSubview:self.containerView];
[self.containerView addSubview:self.oneView]

[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:1];
[UIView setAnimationTransition:UIViewAnimationTransitionCurlUp forView:self.containerView cache:YES];
[self.oneView removeFromSuperview];
[self.containerView addSubview:twoView];
[UIView commitAnimations];
```

Now it was aware of device rotation and worked correctly for both landscape orientation.
But it worked from down to up (started with right-bottom corner) as it described in docs.
But I want it to work from right to left.
I also tried to use transform property of views like:

```
self.containerView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(-M_PI_2);
self.oneView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI_2);
```

It didn't help.
So, a question is:
How to use transition UIViewAnimationTransitionCurlUp in landscape mode (both left and right) for transition between views from right to left?
Thanks for any help!
Alex

Comment: Could you make the transition right to left?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using `UIViewAnimationTransitionCurlDown`? It is the reverse direction of `UIViewAnimationTransitionCurlUp`.

Comment: Yes, actually I'm using both UIViewAnimationTransitionCurlUp and UIViewAnimationTransitionCurlDown to move between several images forward and backward. I just simplified description of issue a bit, to avoid unrelated things.